# How to disable Share and Look up in UITextView

Tags: swift, menu, uitextview

I am trying to hide the text menus except for `copy` and two original menus.

I used the following code to suppress pretty much everything... but somehow, I can not hide `look up` and `share` (as well as `Spell` and `Speak`, added Jun 10).

```
  override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if  action == Selector(("_lookup:")) ||
        action == Selector(("_share:"))
    {
        return false
    } else  if
        action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) ||
            action == #selector(copyAll(_:))  ||
            action == #selector(lookUpWord (_:))
    {
        return true
    } else {
    
    return false
    }
}
```

I debugged the code and witnessed that the function does return false when `lookup` and `share` went into the if-statement. But, somehow this is not reflected on the menu.

How can I make sure to disable `look up`, `share`, `Spell`, and `Speak`?

----- updated ----

**Modified as extension**
But somehow still not working in the way I want. The menu does not reflect the code in this extension...

```
   extension UITextView {
    open override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if  action == Selector(("_lookup:")) ||
                action == Selector(("_share:"))
        {
            return false
        } else  if
            action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) ||
                action == #selector(ViewController.copyAll(_:))  ||
                action == #selector(ViewController.lookUpWord (_:))
        {
            return true
        } else {
            
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling canPerformAction?

Comment: I’m putting this code in `ViewController` without subclassing `UITextView`. Do I need to subclass?

Comment: Try putting it in an extension to UITextView.

Comment: Thank you! I tried putting it as an extension. But somehow still not working in the way I want. The menu does not reflect the code in this extension. Could you look at my edited question to see where I am not doing it right?

Comment: You only want to exclude lookup and share?

Comment: I can exclude share, but for some unknown reason lookup always is there!

Comment: Actually, I want to exclude everything except for copy and my original functions (i.e., copyAll and lookUpWord) . However, for some reason, `look up`, `translation`, and `look up` and `share` still show up. You successfully excluded share? I cannto even do that.. and yeah why `lookup` is always there... (sad face)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create subclass of UITextView with the custom implementation you want.
2. To disable lookup, you need to use `Selector (("_define:"))`.

Here is an example which disables `Share` & `Lookup` option :

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {
    
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        let canPerformAction = super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
        
        let shareAction = NSSelectorFromString("_share:")
        let lookUpAction = NSSelectorFromString("_define:")
        
        if canPerformAction && action == shareAction {
            // Set true/false based on your requirement
            return false
        }
        
        if canPerformAction && action == lookUpAction {
            return false
        }
        
        return canPerformAction
    }
}
```

And use this as:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var yourTextView: CustomTextView!
}
```

**Edit:**

And if you want to find the `Selector` for the Specific actions, Try this way:

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    print("TextView::canPerformAction: \(action)")
    return false
}
```

Select the action and this will print the associated action:

> TextView::canPerformAction:_accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:
> TextView::canPerformAction: _accessibilityPauseSpeaking:
> TextView::canPerformAction: copy:

Or you can place a breakpoint and see what you're getting called with for "action".

Comment: One quick follow-up question, if I may. How can we know the lookup can be caught by specifying `NSSelectorFromString("_define:")`, especially the `_define` part? I tried this on my iPhone and I can see `Spell` and `Speak` are showing up, but I do not know how to catch them in a similar manner as `NSSelectorFromString("_define:")`.

Comment: I've included the way to find the associated action selectors to the Answer. Please check the Edited answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much, @Kush! I have never thought of printing `action` but that is a great idea!! :))